# how do I add horizontal/vertical spacer behaviour to miglayout

Tags: swing, miglayout

I am using migLayout and set it on flowY.
My object then added with a lot of gaps.
Regularly, on swing editor I add vertical or horizontal spacer.
what is the best practice to add it using miglayout ?

Plus - sometimes I put the spacer between components and by that the two components keep the biggest gap they can on the panel. How do I imitate that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest reading the `getting started` document on the migLayout website ([Getting Started PDF](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf)).

To give your custom spacing, I'd suggest using:

```
MigLayout l = new MigMayout (
  "",
  "[][]20[]",
  "[]20[]"
);
```

which is on page 3 of the PDF.